# Python can't receive user data in HTTP socket server

Tags: python, sockets, http, header, recv

I can't get the data in recv()
I want the data that the user inputs in form fields

Code:

```
def recvall(self, conn):
    BUFF_SIZE = 4096 # 4 KiB
    data = ""

    while True:

        packet = conn.recv(BUFF_SIZE).decode('utf-8')
        data += packet

        if len(packet) < BUFF_SIZE:
            break

    print (data)
```

output:

```
POST /search HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 14
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Origin: http://localhost
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Referer: http://localhost/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

It seems to be missing a line or something i've tried everything
i want the data at the end

Comment: This seems an odd termination condition: `if len(packet) < BUFF_SIZE: break`. What are you trying to achieve there?

Comment: i tried: if not packet: break but it kept looping so i just went with that and it worked

Comment: If you really want to implement your own HTTP stack please read the [standard](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) instead of just guessing. The HTTP request consists of a header and an optional body delimited by a new line and the size of the body is given in the header. You cannot just use dumb `recv` in the hope that you get everything but you have to actually properly deal with the HTTP protocol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have stopped reading after the header sequence as Steffen correctly observed. The following code should work (beware, untested!):

```
def recvall(self, conn):
    BUFF_SIZE = 4096

    while True:
        packet = conn.recv(BUFF_SIZE)
        if not packet:
            break
        print packet.decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: it keeps looping and doesn't break

Comment: @OmarAlhussani I modified the code to output right away. See what it gives you. My guess is that the client does not terminate the connection.